# How can I import a CSV file into an SQLite table from the command line?

Tags: sqlite

I need to get data from a PostgreSQL table into an SQLite table.  I am exporting the data from PostgreSQL into a CSV file, and then trying to import it into SQLite from a command-line prompt.  First I tried this:

`c:> /sqlite3/sqlite3 sample.trd ".import source_file.csv trend_data"`

For every line in the file, I got an error message saying SQLite expected three values and there was only one.  Not really surprising because I never told SQLite that the file was a CSV file.  So then I tried this:

`c:> /sqlite3/sqlite3 sample.trd ".mode csv .import source_file.csv trend_data"`

I got no errors, but I also got no data.

Answer (score 5):

Each dot command must be alone in a single line.

You could pipe multiple commands into `sqlite3`, but in this case, it would be easier to set CSV mode with a parameter:

```
sqlite3 -csv sample.trd ".import source_file.csv trend_data"
```